# Upsell: always shows custom text even when price is not 0

Tags: price, custom

When I use this below code for my view.phtml page, when price is 0 then it shows a message, (Price on request). This works. When price is not 0 then it shows the price.

**VIEW WORKS**
/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php if($_product->price==0): ?>
     <?php  echo 'Price on request'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
     <span class="price-yo">Price</span>
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I use the code for my upsell.phtml I **always** get the message, (Price on request) while it needs to show a price when its not 0.

**UPSELL DOESN'T WORK**
/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml

```
<?php if($_product->price==0): ?>
        <div class="price-req-list">Price on request</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div id="priceholder-list-upsell"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

// extra info
*I use special price allot, maybe something is wrong in the price.phtml ?*

Comment: Have you tried `$_product->getPrice()==0`?

Comment: When I use that there is no price or message at all.
 <?php if($_product->getPrice()==0): ?>

Answer (score 1):

*The following is only my thinking, hopefully I didn't overlook some important part in the code*

If `Price on request` is shown, then `$_product->price==0` is true.

There is no `$this->price` in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, therefore I think `Varien_Object::__set` is called which returns:

```
public function __get($var)
{
    $var = $this->_underscore($var);
    return $this->getData($var);
}
```

Which should be the same as `$_product->getPrice()`:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData('price')) {
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this);
    } else {
        return $this->getData('price');
    }
}
```

Something is broken in your upsell collection or price calculation. Whatever it is:

1. you want to use $_price->getPrice() if this doesn't return anything, you need to fix THIS :-)
2. check (hopefully with xdebug) which attributes are selected by the mysql query, somehow the prices aren't fetched...

Answer (score 0):

you can try exstension   Call for Price it allows you set custom text instead of price and also set it shown or not depend of customer group.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/call-for-price-hide-price-3163.html